# c# cannot be referenced from a static function

Tags: c#

c# newbie here.

seems like this user gave me a very good solution for my problem:

[serialport error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034197/serialport-error/3034243#3034243)

but i have no clue how to code up what he suggested. can you please help?

Comment: He only answered your original question an hour ago - have a bit of patience and wait to see if he answers you request for help. 

I don't think opening another question is the most appropriate thing to do here.

Comment: @sgreeve: I understand his confusion: sometimes people get criticized for changing their question instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will compile fine. You'll have to give `thePort` real settings, of course.

```
namespace csWinFormsTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static System.IO.Ports.SerialPort thePort;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            thePort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort("COM1");
        }

        static void fcn()
        {
            MessageBox.Show(thePort.PortName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: im sorry can you take my original code and show me how this fits in?

Answer (score 2):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private static SerialPort serialPort1;
        public class ThreadWork
        {

            public static void DoWork()
            {
                serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
                //stuff
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ThreadStart myThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(ThreadWork.DoWork);
            Thread myThread = new Thread(myThreadDelegate);
            myThread.Start();
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived_1(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            string response = serialPort1.ReadLine();
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => textBox1.AppendText(response + "\r\n")));
        }
    }
```

You don't really need to have DoWork() static though.